# How do I use PHP pthreads when there are more jobs to perform than threads available?

Tags: php, multithreading, pthreads

I found the following simple example of how to implement pthreads in PHP:
http://www.masnun.com/2013/12/15/multithreading-in-php-doing-it-right.html

I got that code to run fine, but for my real-world use case, I have anywhere from 10-20 jobs that I want to run in parallel, but due to system limitations, I cannot create 10-20 threads at the same time.
As such, I was planning on creating 5 threads or so, and then having each of them run a job, and once a thread finishes a job, have it execute another job on the queue.
The idea is that the threads would continue to do this until all the jobs on the queue are finished.

What's the best way to do this?
I'm hoping for simple, easy-to-follow code that can be easily changed as per the use case.
Thank you.

Comment: Are you building within any current framework? Laravel has a Queue library that you could use to do this- have the queue run 5 threads per execution. Sidenote, it sounds like what you're trying to accomplish would realistically be better suited for GoLang or NodeJS until pthreads is a more commonplace solution- especially if you're doing this for speed. You could easily create 20 threads in golang- I've used it with well over 100 at once. EDIT: Why not just call the next worker and tell it to start when your work is completed?

Comment: Switching away from PHP is not an option and we already have a preestablished framework that is not a commonplace framework like Laravel, so unfortunately, neither of those are valid options. However, your third recommendation sounds doable. Are you simply saying that whenever a worker thread ends, I create a new worker thread and run another job from there? Thanks.

Comment: Split your payload like an array according to the nb of thread. Use array chunk for instance to generate batches. Pthreads runs the chuncked  batches, not exiding the threads.

Comment: A second option would be to use pthreads pooling but by experience I find it less efficient to work with instead of a loop chuncked batch that return (join) once finished.

Comment: Thanks, cpugourou. So you're recommending that I chunk things so that, for example, if I had 23 jobs to run and five threads, I would split the jobs up evenly as best I could among the threads, which means that threads 1, 2 and 3 would each run 5 jobs and threads 4 and 5 would run 4 jobs each? Is that what you're saying? Thanks.